# Display C# DateTime in HTML Text Input

Tags: javascript, c#, html, datetime

So I'm pulling a DateTime from a database and I want to display it in an HTML text input (`<input type="text">`).

By the time the C# DateTime is sent to Javascript, it looks something like this: `fooDate: {6/22/2011 2:30:00 PM}`.  But when it is displayed in the `<input>`, it ends up looking like this: `2011-06-22T14:30:00`.

It's kind of annoying because I only care about displaying the *date*.  Why is this this conversion happening, and is there a way to just get it to display the `6/22/2011 2:30:00 PM` bit?  Can this be accomplished without the use of regular expressions?

Comment: how do you display the date in input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix and match whatever combination you want to. World is your oyster.

```
DateTime.Now.Day
DateTime.Now.Month
DateTime.Now.Year
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the String.Format function:

```
//Here you pull the DateTime from your db
//I show you an example with the current DateTime
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now; 

string date = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", myDateTime); //eg: 02-12-2014

//Place the string in your textbox
this.txtYourTextbox.Text = date;
```

if you don't know which format to use, refer to following article:

[String Format for DateTime [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 1):

are you able to convert it to string before you pass it to your JS-Method?

```
string Output = string.Format("{0:G}",DatabaseValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Examples for just getting at the date...

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

will return "02/12/2014"

Or you can specify the format you want

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

will return "2014-12-02"